# pick up date within some range

Tags: sql

I have table like this. This is a record of consultant done activity for aftercare when some new candidate starts a job.I have built a report to compare if aftercare is done on time or not. in the report it start showing 3 days ago that aftercare is due on this date. But some consultants do aftercare before or after and also on date which is correct. I am fetching MIN aftercaredone date to check and compare with the aftercare due date and shows in the report if it is correct like below.

```
MIN(case when DESCRIPTION='Aftercare Pre Start' then DUEDATECONCAND end) DUEDATEPreStart  hin
```

But my min date logic fails here. Actually I like to pick up all aftercaredone dates and compare with aftercareduedate . If any date falls within required period then should show report result correct otherwise fails. I mean if someone did aftercare within 3 days difference from AFtercareduedate then should show correct or otherwise in query it should show N(means not done). And also I need to exclude weekends.

```
ConsultantID    CandiateID   candidateNAME      AfterCareDueDate   AftercareDone
123                1            Bob             01/02/2019         20/02/2019
123                1            Bob             01/02/2019         01/02/2019
123                1            Bob             01/02/2019         07/02/2019
100                2            Rob             01/02/2019         01/02/2019
100                2            Rob             01/02/2019         10/02/2019
200                3            ABC             01/02/2019         20/01/2019
```

Comment: Add some sample data where all relevant columns are included and expected output